# Set the name of deployed war with tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm deploying a multi-module project, with multiple wars to a Tomcat server, and it works almost fine. Here's the part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>${ed.tomcat.server.name}</server>
        <webapps>
            <webapp>
                <groupId>com-mycompany.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
                <version>${ed.project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                <path>/ed-admin</path>
            </webapp>
            <webapp>
                <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
                <version>${ed.project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                <path>/ed-frontend</path>
            </webapp>
        </webapps>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This code deploys an `admin.war` and a `frontend.war` to the Tomcat server, fine. But I'd like to rename those war files, without renaming the Maven module.

I'm googling it for hours, without any results. Can you give me any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the point of changing the name of the WAR file itself, as you can anyway change the contextPath. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: My problem was, that there was an `admin.war` in my Tomcat's `webapps` dir, from an other project. The Tomcat manager refused my deployment procedure. Is there a way, to use the same Tomcat instance for testing, and there possibly will be wars with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works but you can try to use the `<finalName>` tag.

If you using e.g. the following it would create an "myFinalFile.jar instead of the group + artifact id.

```
<build>
    <finalName>MyFinalFile</finalName>
</build>
```

So i would recommend you to test the following pom.xml. the `<finalName>` tag was added within the `<webapp>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>${ed.tomcat.server.name}</server>
        <webapps>
            <webapp>
                <groupId>com-mycompany.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
                <version>${ed.project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                // following line must be configured to your needs
                <finalName>myAdminFileName</finalName>
                <path>/ed-admin</path>
            </webapp>
            <webapp>
                <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
                <version>${ed.project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                // following line must be configured to your needs
                <finalName>myFrontendFileName</finalName>
                <path>/ed-frontend</path>
            </webapp>
        </webapps>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Didn't see any. Just the war appeared with the same, unchanged name. I'm gonna look for errors soon, and write a comment. Thanks!

Comment: you also could try <warName>myFrontendFileName.war</warName> instead of <finalName>... this yould help you when executing the goal war:war. By the way: which goal is executed anyways?

Comment: `mvn clean install tomcat:deploy`